# Can't Read *.ttf File

Tags: java, fonts, java-io

I'm programming a dictionary for a language I'm creating. The language does not use any English letters, so I created my own font using free online software at http://www.myscriptfont.com/, which would hopefully allow me to use my language's symbols. The first step to make this dictionary would then be to import this custom font, but it's not working. Here's the part of the code where I import it:

```
    /**
     * Constructor for class Bank
     */
    public Bank() throws Exception
    {
        //Previous code creates frame and pane with no problems

        try{
            font1 = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("fonts/ShoriPart1.ttf"));
        }
        catch(IOException|FontFormatException e){
        }
        font1 = font1.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 20);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(font1);
        JList fonts = new JList(ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(fonts));
        JLabel l = new JLabel("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 0123456789");
        l.setFont(font1);
        pane.add(l);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Every time I ran this, it threw the java.io.IOException "Can't read fonts\ShoriPart1.ttf (in java.awt.Font)." I used try/catch to try to prevent that, but it ended up just not creating the font at all. Is there something wrong with the font file? Is there a way to fix this in the code?

Edit: I just tried using the font in Microsoft Word, and it worked fine.

Comment: You have an empty catch-block. Where is the code failing exactly?

Comment: Without try/catch, it says it can't read the file. With try/catch, the next line returns a nullPointerException. So the try/catch really isn't doing anything for me; I just didn't get rid of it.

Comment: An exception means "You cannot continue as if this method worked, because it didn't work."  Ignoring the exceptions does not make `createFont` work.  The exception means it failed, so you should exit your constructor in that catch block, and you need to pay attention to what the exception is telling you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `inputStream` to pass it to createFont function: see if it works!

```
InputStream myStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("font.ttf"));
ttfBase = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, myStream);
```

It happened to me once and passing the stream worked. Don't know actual reason though

Comment: recheck that your file actually exist in the same directory of the class file in which you are trying to read it

Comment: I feel like an idiot... I had the file in the folder of my actual program. I was using another to test it... Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of creating buffered input stream here? Seems to work the same for me only with file input stream.

Answer (score 0):

First tip:  **NEVER HAVE EMPTY CATCH BLOCKS**.  At a bare minimum, you should print the stack trace to `System.out`, but preferable re-throw it.  Bypassing the exception like this is just bad.

Assuming the exception message is the literal string you copied, you may want to make sure that the program can read the folder the file is in (i.e. has permission).  If it does, then it most likely is an issue with the file format.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm new to Java, in case that wasn't obvious. The program should have permission. It's in the source folder which is in My Documents. So it's probably an issue with the font itself?