# How can I stop getting errors about my font not being loaded in Java?

Tags: java

I have a little problem with my game made in entire Java, using no external libraries, except twitter4j.

I have a custom font that I have put into the game, and will be using for the game graphics, but when it loads up it comes up with this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Can't read /font/SpaceBang.ttf
at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1008)
at uk.connorwright.StarGame.Fonts.registerFont(Fonts.java:25)
at uk.connorwright.StarGame.Fonts.<init>(Fonts.java:18)
at uk.connorwright.StarGame.Game.loadFonts(Game.java:119)
at uk.connorwright.StarGame.Game.init(Game.java:88)
at uk.connorwright.StarGame.Game.run(Game.java:150)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

When font with the exact same name is there and the same directory name, this has been happening on all of my computers, Mac, Windows and Linux. This is the font class code:

```
package uk.connorwright.StarGame;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Fonts {

private static ArrayList<Fonts> fontList = new ArrayList<Fonts>();

private static String fontPath;

public Fonts(String filePath){
    // filePath = SpaceBang.ttf
    // Game.FONT_LOCATION = "/font"
    Fonts.fontPath = Game.FONT_LOCATION + filePath;
    registerFont();
}

private void registerFont(){
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

    try{
        ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(fontPath)));
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void addFont(Fonts font){
    fontList.add(font);
}
}
```

and this is the code that I have referring to the font class:

```
public static void loadFonts() {
    Fonts.addFont(new Fonts("/SpaceBang.ttf"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having error in your `registerFont()` method.

Either:

- place your file at proper location -> `Can't read /font/SpaceBang.ttf`
- remove call to this method
- reorganize your method (remove `printStackTrace()`)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by 'place your file at the proper location'?

Comment: You code is trying to find SpaceBang.ttf file under location `/font/SpaceBang.ttf` (according to stacktrace you provided). Is your file located there or elsewhere?

Comment: btw check this out -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592028/cant-read-ttf-file

Comment: I have the font installed on my computer and that directory no where else.